# Bifurcation - first-order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, bifurcation

> Construct a first-order ODE with one critical point if $\left\lvert \mu \right\rvert \ge 1$ and three critical points if $\left\lvert \mu \right\rvert \lt 1$ and draw a bifurcation diagram.

Having trouble thinking up a function for this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First order ODE is defined by single scalar function $f(x)$. What really matters here is the location of zeros of this function. So, draw the plane $(\mu, x)$ and try to sketch some picture which illustrates how zeros of $f(x)$ depend on $\mu$. You might realize that sketched picture might be implemented by some low-order polynomial function $f(x)$.

Comment: Yeah, I did all of that.  My problem is thinking up a function that actually does this.  I've drawn pictures but I still can't figure out what kind of function would actually have these properties.

Comment: Okay, try to think this way. Polynomial can be defined by its roots. Let each root be continuous function depending on bifurcation parameter. Will it help you to sketch any example of such function?

Answer (score 0):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function, the following cubic equation
$$ x^3-\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4}}x+\frac{1}{\mu}=0\tag{1}$$
with $a=1,b=0,c=-\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4}},d=\mu$, has the discriminant
$$ \Delta=18abcd-4b^3d+b^2c^2-4ac^3-27a^2d^2=-27(\frac1{\mu^2}-1).$$
If $\Delta\ge0$ or $|\mu|\ge 1$, (1) has three real roots and if $\Delta<0$ or $|\mu|<1$, (1) has one real root. Therefore the following ODE
$$ x'=x^3-\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4}}x+\mu $$
will be the one you want to construct. Now you can draw bifurcation diagrams.